# Change color for saturday and sunday date field in tree view odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

Is it possible change color line for saturday and sunday date field in tree view?

Comment: what Saturday and Sunday? Please explain in details what you want

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your efforts in your question. I am not sure why these question get upvote without any effects share.

Comment: @Odedra Sorry, I'm edit my questiion. I need red color in tree view where is date day saturday or sunday (For current week 8 and 9 July) in tree view need change color to red.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be not possible with the latest version of Odoo. You could use the new [decorations](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#lists) for that, but the python expression context [doesn't have datetime or any other date library loaded into it](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list_view.js#L209) anymore (i think the old `colors` possibility allowed `datetime` use).

Maybe it will be possible with Odoo 11 again.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `color` field in your model and assign it to `red` when it's Sunday or Saturday.

```py
class YourClass(models.Model):

    @api.one
    def _get_color(self):
        #if it's saturday or sunday
             self.color = "red"

    color = fields.Char("Color", compute=_get_color)
```

Then, you have to modify a little your tree view.

```xml
<tree string="Your tree view" colors="red:color=='red'">
    <field name="color" invisible="True"/>
    ...
</tree>
```

After that, the row in a tree view would be printed as red.

Hope, that will help.